# What's the right way to test this controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm writing a test for a controller, using angular.js + jasmine.

Let's say I have a controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('HomePageCtrl', function($scope, Homepage, posts, topics, photos, sideBar) {
    $scope.slide   = (photos || [])[0];
    $scope.posts   = Homepage.posts(posts);
    $scope.topics  = Homepage.topics(topics);
    $scope.sideBar = sideBar;
    $scope.template = '/templates/home-page.html';
});
```

This controller has only scope variables assignments not functions. How can I write tests for this controller? I need to check if each variables is defined? Each variable has the right value?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the log service (if that is what you mean) to test if your variables are not empty

```
angular.module('logExample', [])
.controller('LogController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {
  $scope.$log = $log;
  $scope.message = 'Hello World!';
}]);
```

Comment: I'm writing a unit test - I'm not understanding how with the log service I can test my controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all initialization logic into an exposed function, to be able to call it from tests.

```
angular.module('app').controller('HomePageCtrl', function($scope, Homepage, posts, topics, photos, sideBar) {

    $scope.activate = function () {
        $scope.slide   = (photos || [])[0];
        $scope.posts   = Homepage.posts(posts);
        $scope.topics  = Homepage.topics(topics);
        $scope.sideBar = sideBar;
        $scope.template = '/templates/home-page.html';
    }

    $scope.activate();
});
```